# Why does this code execute in this order? Looking for explanation of process flow

Tags: ios, swift

In the following code I am looking to pull some attributes from a database - id's who are members of a particular `community`.

I  make another API call to fetch the names of those community members.

```
import UIKit

class ShowCommunityViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var communityName: UILabel!
    var communityIsCalled: String?
    var comIds =  [String]()
    var communityId: Int?
    var communityPlayers =  [String]()
    var communityPlayerIds =  [String]()


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/specificCommunity.php?");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        let postString = "id=\(comIds[communityId!])";
      //  print (postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                     // print (json)
                       if let arr = json?["players"] as? [[String:String]] {
                            let players = arr.flatMap { $0["player_id"]!
                               // print(arr)
                          }
                        print ("one ",players)
                        self.communityPlayerIds = players
                        }

                    } catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        let myUrlTwo = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getPlayers.php?");
        var requestTwo = URLRequest(url:myUrlTwo!);
        requestTwo.httpMethod = "POST";
        let postStringTwo = "player_ids=\(self.communityPlayerIds)";
        print ("two ",postStringTwo)
        requestTwo.httpBody = postStringTwo.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let taskTwo = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestTwo) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                        // print (json)
                        if let arr = json?["player_names"] as? [[String:String]] {
                            let playerNames = arr.flatMap { $0["user_name"]!
                                // print(arr)

                            }
                            print ("three ", playerNames)
                        }



                    } catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
        }
        taskTwo.resume()


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        communityName.text = communityIsCalled

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

If you note the order of the print debug commands `one, two, three`.

They actually execute in order of `two, one, three`.

Because `two` is executing before `one` my Post String does not have the `player_ids` required to look up the names.

Could someone please explain the process flow to me?

Comment: One word: "asynchronous".

Comment: Thanks Maddy - i'm very new to Swift.  Would you mind going into a bit more detail as that doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: It was meant as a hint for you to do some searching. :)

Comment: Imagine, you ask 3 peoples to do your works. First, you ask A, then you ask B, lastly you ask C. Will you receive the result from A first, then from B and then C? No, not sure! It depends on how fast they work for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's strip away everything, leaving just the 3 `print` statements in your code

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
    print("one")
}    
task.resume()

print("two")
let taskTwo = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestTwo) {
    print("three")
}
taskTwo.resume()
```

`URLSession` tasks are executed asynchronously. When you call `task.resume()`, it sends the instructions to another thread and immediately jumps to the next line, without waiting for the `task` to complete. Network requests are extremely slow compared to the CPU's speed so it will almost always print `two` before `one`.

The order of `one` and `three` are uncertain, depending on which one is faster for the server to respond.

Comment: Great! Thank you! So as a solution... have I structured my code incorrectly for what I want to achieve?  Should I be in some way setting flags so one task doesn't begin until the other has finished?

Comment: When you say "almost always print two before one", you can get rid of the "almost".  Since `viewDidAppear` will be running on the main thread and the "one" and "three" print statements are being dispatched to the main thread, "two" must print first.  (Unless there's a pathological case of the application calling `viewDidAppear` -- which it shouldn't -- on a background thread -- which is beyond shouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `dataTask(request:)` is asynchronous. Both tasks are started nearly at once, but the `completionHandler` is called, when the HTTP-Request was finished. This can take different amounts of time for each request.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `DispatchQueue.main.async` you're adding the job to a queue that can run multiple jobs at once, each of those jobs runs in a different amount of time so their results would not necessarily be in the order that you have them in your code.

Theoretically because I'm not familiar with that exact bit of Swift: If there was no call to `DispatchQueue.main.async` then it would execute them in order but it would be blocking, the code would wait for the network request to complete before moving on and the print statements would be in order.